# Can we use WiFi Technology as Bluetooth's?

Tags: wifi

IS it possible to send data between two phones using WiFi only... That is without use of WiFi-direct, router and internet?
Are there any tutorials, Libraries or research papers ???

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct is meant to send data between two phones without the need for an intermediary. Why do you want to avoid using it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's exactly what WiFi direct is for... There are some other more esoteric possibilities as well, though I doubt your device supports them - check out the WiFi IBSS mode and [BT HS](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/High-Speed.aspx) protocol (it uses both BT and a 3rd-party RF, such as WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
If your a android user you can use this application
[wififiletransfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer)

For IOS and other OS's they have their own WiFi direct apps.

If you a desktop user hope below article is useful
http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-Wirelessly